# How to filter BoltCM setcontent by releated ContentTypes?

Tags: php, symfony, silex, bolt-cms

Now we can do:
`{% setcontent books = 'books' where {price: '<30.00'} %}`

But how can I fetch books filtered by its author in a scenario where books and authors are two ContentTypes and authors is a relation to books (instead of having the authors id as foreign on books)?

Something like pseudo:
`{% setcontent books = 'books' where {related: {authors: author}} %}` (`author` is the current record on template). Or what we already do with taxonomies: https://docs.bolt.cm/content-fetching#using-taxonomies

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying the 'books' and somehow filtering on it having a certain realtion, you should do it the other way around: You know the 'author', and you can use that to get the related records, using `{{ author.related() }}`.

Comment: And if I need to filter by more than one related content? Like `authors` and `categories`.

A simple SQL query wold be: `SELECT * FROM books WHERE author_id = ? AND category_id = ?`

My pseudo: `{% setcontent books = 'books' where {related: {authors: author, categories: category}} %}`